# How to track search queries in my Android app with Google Analytics?

Tags: android, search, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a custom search engine in my app, and I would like to track

1. What search queries users are typing into the EditText
2. What search result users are clicking on from the results list
3. How many searches a user makes per session

Is this possible? How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use [EasyTracker](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/parameters), and API that's made for your need. Obviously there are some changes going on there, as it says something about V2 and limited beta, but I used it several months ago, and it's really just a few lines of code, and you can specify yourself, what's being tracked.